# Drag visual is far away from the pointer

Tags: c#, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

The objects to drag are placed in a Xaml grid with 50 rows and 50 columns. The fields are 96 of 96 points.

The drag visual that is shown during the drag operation is attached to the pointer, but far away from the pointer (look at the attached picture).

Is it possible, to keep the visual near from the pointer? Is there a mechanism between the pointer and the drag visual? In this case, the distance to the visual becomes greater the further away the pointer form the first field (top - left) ist. There is an explanation for this behavior?

[image]

Comment: Not sure I'm following.  However, does the offset from what you see relative to what you want say the same for close and far cases?  If you move the window to the corners of the screen, does the offset stay the same?  If the former seems wrong, check your calculations.  If the latter, check if you are working in screen or _client_ coordinates

Comment: It might be easier to help with minimal reproducible code.

Comment: @Flydog57, thanks for your evaluation. It seems there is a connection. If the first field  is moved in the window to the top left corner of the screen, the position of the drag visual is perfect, also near to the mouse pointer. The drag function is enabled by the property CanDrag or by the method StartDragAsync of the UiElement. The system calculate the distance to the visual. .. any idea, how i can correct the drag visual distance?

Comment: You need to do a screen coordinates to client coordinates transformation. I'm not a WPF guy, but it shouldn't be hard to figure this out

Comment: Ok thanks, i try to find out, i know the lead. The application is a windows app based on Net6

Comment: Just search for "screen client coordinates transform wpf" and you should find a solution

Comment: Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information? I cannot reproduce with the [Drag and drop sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/xamldraganddrop/).

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT, thanks for answering. The code behind ist to complex to crate an executable example. Actualy it seems, its a subject of rendering of the layout, because the the structure of the surface with the tiles is realized programmaticly....